# If $f: [0, 1] \to \mathbb R$ is defined by $() =  ^2$, check $f$ is bijective or not?how?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If $f:  [0, 1] \to \mathbb R$ is  defined by $() =  ^2$,   check $f$ is bijective or not?how?
I don't think it is onto because 6 doesn't have any pre image but 6 belongs to R

Comment: Do you mean $f(x) = x^2$ ?

Comment: Yess it is f(x)=x²

Comment: Surely you have some ideas here.  Please edit your post to include them.  Do you believe the map is bijective?   In particular, do you believe it is surjective?

Comment: I am not getting anything
I can solve this for N>N R>R but cant find this

Comment: Do you know what surjective means?

Comment: Onto function
Which has preimage for all of it's range

Comment: Post edit, sure!  $6$ is not in the image of $f(x)$, and that's all you need.  Even more obviously, $-1$ is not in the image of $f(x)$.

Comment: So it is not onto am i right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Also, is it one-one?

Comment: Is it one-one? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not surjective, to be bijective you  need it to be both injective and surjective

surjective $\forall$ y $\exists$ x such that $y=f(x)=x^2$

let $y=-3$ (or y=3) then $x=\sqrt(-3)$ but $\sqrt(-3) \notin [0,1]$

injective $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ if and only if $x_1=x_2$

since the domain is in [0,1], yes it is

Comment: Thank You Very Much